# MessageQueue Quirks while Sending Messages

Tags: msmq

Writing to remote MSMQ seems to be working on/off. I am not sure what is wrong and what else to do to confirm sending.

I am reluctant to setup some kind of ack. It seems to be an overkill.

```
  using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queueName, QueueAccessMode.Send))
      {
        var messageQueueTransaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
        messageQueueTransaction.Begin();
        try
        {
          queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(EmailMessage) });
          var msg = new Message();
          msg.Label = emailMessage.Subject;
          msg.Body = emailMessage;
          queue.Send(msg, messageQueueTransaction);
          messageQueueTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          LoggerLib.Logger.ErrorException(e, "Error Sending Email using MSMQ", emailMessage);
          messageQueueTransaction.Abort();
        }
        finally
        {
          queue.Close();
        }
      }
```

The Connection string for MSMQ is in the format of:"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:FULLMACHINENAME\private$\emailmessagequeue"

Also, I used "FormatName:DIRECT:TCP:IPAddress\private$\emailmessagequeue".

It works without a glitch when I ran it locally. So, I allowed Everyone to have Full access and It still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The port number 1801 was blocked. That resolved it.

Comment: Please add this as an answer to your question - then it will help others with the same problem as you. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port number 1801 was blocked. That resolved it. –